# Suitable plot for 5 dimensional feature vectors?

Tags: clustering, multidimensional-scaling

I have a list of personality scores obtained from 100 people, based on the Big-Five personality test.
Each person has one score for each of the five assessed traits. I put these scores into a 5 dimensional feature vector, so each person's personality is now represented by this 5 element vector.

I would like to find out how personality traits correlate in each person. For example, if someone scores high on extroversion, how does he score on openness? And I would like to find out if I can generalise this and if people's scores tend to cluster or are more dispersed.

My long term goal is to build a personality recogniser, and I would like to train a model for each personality cluster (if they exist).

How can I approach this? In 3d space I would make a 3d scatter plot of the data and see how it is distributed. But how do I go on about doing it for 5 dimensions?

If you know of any statistical measures that could help, I am open for suggestions (I'm not a statistician and don't know much about this).

Thanks in advance!